# Can I put param in URL of Google Docs document and print it inside of document?

Tags: google-docs

I want to add to URL &p1=v1

And in script make something like this: replace('$$p1$$', v1);

Is it possible?

I googled, but din't find anything useful.

Comment: This is possible with an Apps Script [WebApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web), would you be interested in this solution?

Comment: I think yes. BTW, why it's not possible to use document.location in script inside document? Why do we need extra application?

Comment: `document.location` is a javascript property. Normal Apps Script scripts acecpt only Apps Script specific syntax. On he flipside the WebApp can consist of both Apps Script and Javascript parts and the two can be made to interact. Also, when you publish the WebApp - it will have an URL. To do what you want, you would need to append the URL parameters to the URL of the WebApp - not to the one of the document directly. You can pass the document id as a third parameter.

Answer (score 0):

### How to replace text in a Google Docs document with an Apps Script Web App

- Create an [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script) file
- Design the script as a [Web App](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web) by

  - creating a `doGet(e)` function
  - define how [event parameters](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#request_parameters) shall be interpreted
- Make a call to [DocumentApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document) using the [replaceText()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#replacetextsearchpattern,-replacement) method
- If desired - create an [Html output](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html)
- [Deploy the script as a WebApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#deploying_a_script_as_a_web_app)
- Call the WebApp URL with paramters

**Sample WebApp code:**

```js
function doGet(e) {
  var id = e.parameter.id;
  var search = e.parameter.search;
  var replace = e.parameter.replace;
  var document = DocumentApp.openById(id);
  document.getBody().replaceText(search, replace);
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("All instances of " + search + " have been succesfully replaced by " + replace);
}
```

**Sample WebApp URL:**

`https://script.google.com/a/XXXXX/exec`

**Sample URL call with parameters:**

`https://script.google.com/a/XXXXX/exec?id=YYYYY&search=p1&replace=v1`